# Migration from Windows Authentication to Login page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app where the user is authenticated using Windows Authentication  from AD without a login page. Since the app is used by multiple users who work on the same workstation, a new requirement came up that the users can enter their windows login when opening the web app. Because otherwise, they would have to login to windows with their credentials to be authenticated with their user name.

I would love to have just the native chrome browser pop up where the user can enter username and password to access the page. Can you give me some hints on where to start? I couldn't find anything. Do I have to implement the call to the AD myself or is there a built in middleware who does this for me?

What I have learned so far is that I cannot use Windows Authentication in this case but have to revert to use other middleware.

Edit: I deactivated Windows Authentication and managed to set up a login page and check user/password against the AD server:

```
@layout LoginLayout
@page "/Login"
@using Merbag.DataAccessLayer.UserRecertification
@using System.DirectoryServices
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject UserRecertificationContext userRecertContext
@inject NavigationManager navManager
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
    <div id="formContent">         

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <EditForm Model="@userCredentials" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>User Name :</label>
                <input type="text" @bind-value="userCredentials.UserName" id="login" class="fadeIn second" placeholder="login" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> userCredentials.UserName)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" @bind-value="userCredentials.Password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" placeholder="password" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> userCredentials.Password)" />
            </div>        
              <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
        
        </div>
        </EditForm>

    </div>
</div>

@if (showAuthenticationError)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <p>@authenticationErrorText</p>

    </div>
}
@code {


    private bool showAuthenticationError { get; set; } = false;
    private string authenticationErrorText = "";
    private AuthenticationUserModel userCredentials { get; set; } = new AuthenticationUserModel();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {

        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
        entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myldap");
        entry.Username = userCredentials.UserName;
        entry.Password = userCredentials.Password;

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userCredentials.UserName + ")";

        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        if (result == null)
        {
            //return false;
        }
        else
        {
            
            navManager.NavigateTo("/Index", true);
        }
    }

    public class AuthenticationUserModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

The call against the AD server obviously works, I receive the user name and other stuff. Now I'm struggling to tell the app that this user is an actual user and he should be treated as such, i.e. the `<AuthorizeView>` should work.

[image]

Comment: Why would you have multiple users using the same workstation under one user account?

Comment: It's a workstation located in a garage where 20 people work. Multiple users use this workstation to access car dealer management system and so on. Not sure if they use a generic windows login of if the first guy arriving at the morning logs on using his own credentials. My app is used to create requests for times of absence (e.g. when someone arrives late that day, did a wrong clocking or went to the doctor) which must be confirmed by a superior.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication not support this, unless you use another domain, it will show the prompt window.

**For more details, you can check below post, it should be useful to you.**

[Force widows authentication in .NET 3.1 to always prompt for username and password to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518783/force-widows-authentication-in-net-3-1-to-always-prompt-for-username-and-passwo)

Comment: I have edited my original post with some more information.